# Auto Size Embed Code

Tags: html, resize

Hey, I'm just wondering what code I could use to auto change the size of the video being embedded before it gets displayed.

Example, I need to have it find all instances of this

width="*any value*" height="*any value*"

and replace them with this

width="540" height="405"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly are you embedding the video? There are javascript libraries such as [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) or [jQuery Media](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) that allow you to set the height/width of a flash object when the page loads.

Alternatively you could use a little bit of jQuery to alter the height/width attributes after the fact.

```
$('object').attr('height', 405);
$('object').attr('width', 540);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just wrap them in a common div. Class it with something like `.videoWrap`

then you could simply style it as:

```
.videoWrap object, .videoWrap embed{
    width:540px;
    height:405px;
}
```